# How I can color the entire row using the information from the entity?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have the following table in a `.xhtml` file. I want to color the entire row of the table, not only the text background. How can I do this in `RichFaces`?

Note: the table has more columns, I just posted here one of them.

```html
<rich:panel styleClass="container dynamic grey table col7">
    <f:facet name="header">#{msg.toop_normalverteilungstest_results}</f:facet>

    <rich:dataTable styleClass="dynamic equicol7"
        value="#{normalverteilungstestBean.statisticResultsList}" var="stat" id="table">

        <rich:column id="testschritteVal" styleClass="col1-table" headerClass="col1-table">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.masterdata_normalverteilungstest_testschritte}" />
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputLabel rendered="#{stat.color == 'g'}" style="background-color:MediumSeaGreen;"
                value="#{stat.testschritte}" styleClass="col1" />

            <h:outputLabel rendered="#{stat.color == 'r'}" style="background-color:Tomato;"
                value="#{stat.testschritte}" styleClass="col1" />

            <h:outputLabel rendered="#{stat.color == 'w'}" value="#{stat.testschritte}" styleClass="col1" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
</rich:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `rowClass` attribute. Just combine this with CSS. For example:

```css
<style>
    tr.g { background-color: MediumSeaGreen; }
    tr.r { background-color: Tomato; }
    tr.w { background-color: white; }
</style>
```

and `rowClass="#{stat.color}"` in `rich:dataTable`.